# issue installing twilio module in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, twilio

In my Mac I have installed Python 2.7.12 and it works correctly if I enter the command "python" in the terminal it promp for python commands. Also I have Idle installed and it is working correctly too.

Now I would like to install the Twilio module, I did [all the steps][1] I run "sudo easy_install twilio" and this is the result:

```
Searching for twilio
Best match: twilio 6.3.dev0
Processing twilio-6.3.dev0-py2.7.egg
twilio 6.3.dev0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio-6.3.dev0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for twilio
Finished processing dependencies for twilio
```

I guess that everything went ok, but the problem is when I ran the command "import twilio" it said `ImportError: No module named twilio`

I also did the process using pip and the result is the is the same.

Any help on this will be appreciate.

Comment: I really don't know why someone without trying to help downvote the question, at least let everybody know why the downvote...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have more than one version of python installed in your machine try to check the directory that it installed to

Comment: I used `which python` command and I got this: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python, so I guess I don't have to python version installed

Comment: Okay try to re install online installation is better I guess

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I downloaded the package and I installed manually with `python setup.py install` and now it is working, thanks again